# SQL Insert when not exists

Tags: mysql, insert, exists

I searched a while for this problem, but I can't solve it...

I want to check if a record doesn't exists in a mysql table and then insert a record.

Here is my code:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM personOffice WHERE personID = 2 AND officeID = 1)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO personOffice (personID, officeID) VALUES ('2', (SELECT officeID FROM offices WHERE title = 'Berlin'))
    END
```

Mysql tells me that theres a syntax-error in my first line.

Thanks for your solutions.

Comment: See previously posted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO personOffice(personID, officeID) 
SELECT '2', (SELECT officeID FROM offices WHERE title = 'Berlin') FROM dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM personOffice WHERE personId = 2 AND officeID = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try this :

```
INSERT INTO personOffice (personID, officeID) 
VALUES ('2', (SELECT officeID FROM offices WHERE title = 'Berlin')) 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM personOffice WHERE personID = 2 AND officeID = 1)
```